# How Do I Redirect Wordpress Pages but not posts?

Tags: posts, pages, redirect

I have a client that changed jobs. He wants to redirect all pages on the wordpress site to a specific page on that site. But he also wants to keep all the SEO from the blog posts. So I need all the blog posts to show up, but redirect any old pages to the new page. So, for example:

oldpage.com > oldpage.com/specificpage

so anything that is not a blog post goes to oldpage.com/specificpage

the blogpost would go to blogpost

I am able to redirect everything to oldpage.com/specificpage

I have excluded the homepage and /wp-admin/ etc.

But there are over 4,000 posts and to redirect each one individually is impractical
Is there a way to redirect everything except the posts through .htaccess?

Comment: What are your permalink settings like? Are blogposts on a distinguishable path such as `example.com/blog/{post slug}`?

Comment: Yes. Each post has a distinct name.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the following code to your `functions.php` or create a custom plugin with the code.

```
function my_custom_page_redirect() {
  if (is_page()) {
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_page_redirect');
```

Note - change the URL in `wp_redirect()` to whatever the 'specificpage' is. I just used `home_url()` in the redirect as an example.

Comment: From the Codex: `Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;:`

Comment: Good catch @Abhik and thanks for pointing that out, missed that point.

Comment: I updated the code sample to include the call to `exit;`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this through .htaccess?